# When a translation of an original name of a source is provided in a footnote of an academic text, how do I format reference to the source language?

Tags: academic-writing, translation

I am translating an academic text into English. The text contains a lot of terminology and source names in several different languages. The rules of the source language of the text require shortening of the word "originally" or the name of the source language before citing the text in that language when it follows the translation either in the body of the text or in footnotes.

Example:
*Post and Domestic Times* (orig.: *Post-och Inrikes Тidningar*)
or
*Post and Domestic Times* (Swed.: *Post-och Inrikes Тidningar*)

How should I format it in English?

Comment: Where is it written that which rules of what source language require shortening anything?

Comment: I would suggest starting with a particular source language official corpora, they usually can be googled. There woukld be links and references to approved language tools, official points of reference etc. Another good option would be searching for the official book publishing standards (in that language). Or simply going through examples of official publications (academic, scientific, fiction... depending on what you need) in a country where your source language is official or has a national or regional status.

Comment: If you must go to that much trouble, that's your own choice. If you're working on an academic text, is this not for an English academic institution?

If it is, said institution should have its own clear rules…

Answer (score 2):

In an academic context (that is for a publication that targets an academic audience), if you translate a text, *do not translate the titles of the sources* given in that text. That would give the impression that you were using a translation. You may translate the title of the source after the original title, for example like this:

> MLA:
> de Saint-Exupéry, Antoine. *Le Petit Prince [The Little Prince]*. Gallimard, 1943.

> APA:
> de Saint-Exupéry, A. (1943). *Le petit prince* [The little prince]. Paris, France: Gallimard.

In a non-academic context, such as non-fiction books, sometimes the original sources are replaced with translations of those sources, if they exist. Then simply cite the translated sources (and the page numbers in the translations) and do not mention the original foreign language publication at all. E.g.

> de Saint-Exupéry, Antoine. *Le Petit Prince*. Gallimard, 1943.

becomes

> de Saint-Exupéry, Antoine. *Der kleine Prinz*. Arche, 1950.

Comment: If you like. The tense isn't that important here, so pick whichever you like more

Comment: What if the source language uses non-Latin characters? E.g.,
Кентржинський Б. "Політична пропаганда в Україні напередодні Полтавської битви" [Kentrschynskyj, Bohdan.  Political Propaganda in Ukraine on the Eve of the Battle of Poltava]. Buenos Aires, Argentina, 1954

or
Kentrschynskyj, Bohdan. Politychna propahanda v Ukraiini naperedodni Poltavskoii bytvy [Political Propaganda in Ukraine on the Eve of the Battle of Poltava]. Buenos Aires, Argentina, 1954.
Which option do I use? Or is it OK to just write the title in the target language and indicate the source language of the publication?